# mqtt mosquitto windows xp cygwin1

Tags: windows, cygwin, mosquitto

im new it mqtt, im trying to install mosquitto 1.4.11 cygwin.exe (binary), however im having problems, when i try to run the program i receive a message about cygwin1.dll (file missing), i've installed openSSL in C://, ive installed also cygwin version 2.874 (file setup-x86.exe) in c:// too, then when i copy cygwin1.dll to windows folder and i execute again mosquitto i receive the message: Can not find the entry point of the cancelsynchronousio procedure in the kernel32.dll dynamic link library, 
Can you explain me the correct method to install mosquitto?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [mqttfx](http://www.mqttfx.org/) . Is usefully and friendly interface.

Comment: Mosquitto is however a broker